# How to resolve 'No module named' error with openai and requests in Python web2py project on Azure web apps service?

Tags: module, python-requests, openai-api

I am using python and web2py framework for my openai project to write long form content and short form content including Wordpress integration for publishing the generated article. I am using Microsoft Azure web apps service and workbench tool to connect database.

I installed all of the dependencies as per the requirement to run the project. The project was running fine earlier, suddenly I am having the issues of <class 'ImportError'> No module named name found for openai and requests.
I installed pip install openai, pip install requests.  It is showing requirement already satisfied, but whenever I run the app it is showing module openai not found.

I installed the dependencies in the GitHub requirements.txt file too. I run pip install -r requirements.txt in the SSH but every time it was showing  No module named name found for openai.

Is there anyone can help me to resolve the issue please.

Expecting to resolve the issue please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.